# Slow file transfer using eclipse Saros RTC plugin with an openfire xmpp server

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012-r2, xmpp

I set an Openfire xmpp server on Windows Server 2012 R2, using Amazon ec2.

When trying to share file over an IM client (such as Psi) the file transfer speed between two clients can reach over 1Mb/s, yet when using Saros on eclipse the speed is stuck on 16Kb/s. when using a public server such as lightwitch.org the speed is much faster.

What are possible settings i can change on the server side in order to speed up the Saros file transfer?

This is the server:
ec2-50-112-150-21.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

I am fairly new to servers so please be kind...